# Alloy and webpro

Tags: alloy

I am new in alloy and I have a task relating to Alloy.

I have to model a protocol in alloy and that protocol is a web protocol.

I have a sender,receiver and an intermediate entity.

I wrote signatures on these entities but I don't know how to run this model.

I tried to understand the example of an address book of a email client but when I execute the example it produces a lot of instances of one simple book that maps a name to exactly one address.

I thought that 3 signatures are in the model that is Book,Name and Addr. and if we run this model for run for 3 but Book 1 then how many instances the example will produce? 9? 18? or more?

---

I want to model a web protocol in ALLOY and basic entities for communication are three.
Three entities send messages and receive messages and each message is stickied to specific time like message o to time0,message 1 to time1.

I am facing a lot of difficulties in protocol modeling through Alloy,specially message sequences making and working with other sequences of messages.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Your web protocol can without a doubt be specified in Alloy.

Alloy allows you to generate satisfiable instances by running predicates or allows to find counter examples by checking assertions.

This instance generation will actually help you to verify certain property of your model, and will allow you to correct your model if certain of the expected properties are not met.
(You can thus incrementally improve your model thanks to instance generation).

The number of instances produced will depend of the number of satisfiable instances present in the domain framed by your scope.

Please add some more details to your question in order for us to answer more specifically.